# initializing a vector of structs with array of structs

Tags: c++, vector

I tried the normal way

```
typedef struct
{
int distance; //distance to the next stop
int fuel;     //the fuel at the stop
}stopInfo;

int main()
{
    vector<stopInfo> swapper;   
    int numCases,i,initFuel,distance,numStops;
    stopInfo *I;
    scanf("%d",&numCases);
    for(i=0;i<numCases;i++)
    {   
        scanf("%d",&numStops);      
        I=(stopInfo *)malloc(sizeof(stopInfo)*numStops+2);  
        for(i=0;i<numStops;i++)   scanf("%d %d",&I[i].distance,&I[i].fuel);             
        scanf("%d %d",&distance,&initFuel); 
        I[numStops].fuel=initFuel;  I[numStops].distance=distance; //for starting point
        I[numStops+1].fuel=0;  I[numStops+1].distance=0;           //for destination
        //sort in decresing order of distance.

            vector<stopInfo> v;  v.assign(I,I+numStops+2);

            sort(v.begin(),v.end(),customCompare);
        for(i=0;i<numStops+2;i++)     //copy back in array
        {
            I[i].distance=v[i].distance;
            I[i].fuel=v[i].fuel;    
        }       

        for(i=0;i<numStops+1;i++)
        I[i].distance=I[i].distance-I[i+1].distance;        
        printf("%d\n",fxMemoWrap(I,numStops,initFuel)); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but it gives an error

> a.out: malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++. If you have to use something like that, use `new[]`.

Comment: You wanted to write `I=(stopInfo *)malloc(sizeof(stopInfo)*(numStops+2));`. You allocate `numStops` of `stopInfo` and **2 bytes**. And then you add `numStops+2` of `stopInfo` to a `std::vector<stopInfo>`

Comment: @ishan3243: Run your code through Valgrind. I definitely see amazingly high chances of memory corruption and memory leaks are there for sure.

Comment: This is not "the normal way" by any definition. Not using a redundant intermediate array would be normal.